# How to account for full request time in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am having trouble debugging some unreasonably slow POST requests  via ssl on nginx w/ uwsgi upstream.

I am successfully logging $request_time, $upstream_header_time, $upstream_connect_time, and $upstream_response time like so:

```
log_format upstream_log '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '                                                      
                             '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '                                                               
                             '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'                                                                 
                             'rt=$request_time uct="$upstream_connect_time" uht="$upstream_header_time" urt="$upstream_response_time"';
```

The logs show that the $request_time is typically 2.059 seconds, and that the three upstream variables in total, amount to less than 0.05 seconds.

This rules out uwsgi as the bottle neck.

Client side, using google dev tools, shows the POST is reasonably fast to arrive to the server (0.7 seconds), and then there is a little more than 2 seconds of waiting. So there is a server issue.

The GET requests over SSL are fast, so not maybe it's not SSL (although would be nice to log the handshake time and confirm, but I don't know if there is a parameter for this .. do you?).

So my question is, how do I account for the remaining 2.00 seconds so that I can begin to get to the bottom of the matter?

Are there any other log parameters I can activate that will allow me to do so?

Comment: That covers most everything. How big are these POST requests? Large requests may get buffered to a file on disk before being sent upstream.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you. Yes, I thought I was just sending a JSON containing a bunch of strings. On closer inspection there was a base64 thumbnail being including in each post bloating it's size too 100Kb. Cutting this out reduced the request_time to 190ms. For the sake of finality, it would be nice to know if there is any log variable variable on the Nginx side that would have allowed me to see the time spent buffering to disk. I'm guessing the answer to this is no ...

Comment: I don't know of any such variable. But you can also increase the [buffer size](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size) if you need to send larger POST request bodies without nginx creating temporary files on disk.